# Finding the exact values of $\sin 4x - \sin 2x = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

So I've used the double angle formula to turn

$$\sin 4x - \sin 2x = 0$$

$$2\sin2x\cos2x - \sin2x = 0$$

$$\sin2x(2\cos2x - 1) = 0$$

---

$$\sin2x = 0$$

$$2x = 0$$

$$x = 0$$

---

$$2\cos2x - 1 = 0$$

$$2\cos2x = 1$$

$$\cos2x = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$2x = 60$$

$$x = 30$$

---

With this information I am able to use the unit circle to find

$$x = 0,30,180,330,360$$

However, when I looked at the answers, $$x = 0,30,90,150,180,210,270,330,360$$

Can someone tell me how to obtain the rest of the values for $x$.

Thanks

Comment: One problem is that when $\sin(2x)=0$, there are more solutions than $2x=0$.  In fact you may have $2x=0$, $2x=180$, $2x=360$, ...

Comment: @MichaelBurr I cant see any more values for sin(2x) = 0 other than 0,180 and 360.

But looking at what you just said, am i supposed to divide my current values by 2 to create 90?

2x = 180   x=90 ?

Comment: Remember that sine is periodic, so you might also need $2x=540$ and $2x=720$ because, after dividing by $2$, $x$ is, at most, $360$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelBurr How do i find the rest of the values for cos(2x) = 1/2 ?

Comment: Basically, you must memorize important values of sine and cosine.

Comment: i know cosx = 30 and that it includes 30,150,210,330. But aren't 150 and 210 considered to be negative because they aren't in quad A or C in the unit circle? @MichaelBurr

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\cos(2x) = \frac{1}{2}$ has other solutions in the interval $[0, 360)$ besides $30$.  What are they?  Does $\sin(2x) = 0$ have any others besides what you find?  Ask yourself what values of $2x$ you have to look at to find all of the values of $f(x)$ for $x \in [0, 360)$.  Does this help?

An alternative (less formal) approach to this problem is to think about what $\sin(4x)$ and $\sin(2x)$ look like.  From this it is clear that there will need to be $8$ solutions in $[0, 360)$ and a little thought will tell you how they have to be spaced.

Comment: I understand how there are other values for cosx = 30. But aren't the other values considered to be negative for it as they arent in the same quadrant in the unit circle? Right now I am only considering quadrant A and quadrant C for cosx. However, I can't see any other values for sin2x = 0 other than 0, 180 and 360

Answer (score 2):

Notice, you should consider all the possible values of $x$ in the respective interval, $$\sin 2x(2\cos 2x-1)=0$$
consider the following two cases,

1. $$\sin 2x=0$$$$\implies 2x=n\pi\ \ \ or\ \ \ x=\frac{n\pi}{2}$$
   Where, $n$ is any integer

Now, for the interval $x\in [0, 2\pi]$, setting $n=0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ one should get 
$$x=\color{blue}{0, 90^\circ, 180^\circ, 270^\circ, 360^\circ}$$

2. $$2\cos 2x-1\iff \cos 2x=\frac{1}{2}=\cos\frac{\pi}{3} $$ $$\implies 2x=2n\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{3}\ \ \ or\ \ \ x=n\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Now, for the interval $x\in [0, 2\pi]$, setting $n=0, 1, 2$ one should get 
$$x=\color{blue}{30^\circ, 150^\circ, 210^\circ, 330^\circ}$$

Hence, writing the complete solution for $x$, one should get
$$x=\color{red}{0, 30^\circ, 90^\circ, 150^\circ, 180^\circ, 210^\circ, 270^\circ, 330^\circ, 360^\circ}$$

Comment: I understand your cases, but how did you apply the nπ into the equation and give n certain numbers? @Harish-Chandra-Rajpoot

Comment: good question, sorry, I should have mentioned that $n$ is any integer hence select all the integer values of $n$ such that the values of $x$ obtained should lie in the respective interval as mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula: $$\sin x-\sin y=2\sin\frac{x-y}{2}\cos\frac{x+y}{2},$$ we have:

$$\sin 4x-\sin 2x=2\sin\frac{4x-2x}{2}\cos\frac{4x+2x}{2}=2\sin x\cos 3x.$$
Now, 
$$\sin 4x-\sin 2x=0$$
$$2\sin x\cos 3x=0$$
$$\sin x\cos 3x=0$$
$$\sin x=0\Rightarrow x=k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z},$$
and
$$\cos 3x=0\Rightarrow 3x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{k\pi}{3}, k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(4x)-\sin(2x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(4x)=\sin(2x)$$

---

Take the inverse sine of both sides:

---

- $$4x=\pi-2x+2\pi n_1\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$6x=\pi+2\pi n_1\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$x=\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi n_1}{3}$$
- $$4x=2x+2\pi n_2\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$2x=2\pi n_2\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$x=\pi n_2$$

With $n_1,n_\in\mathbb{Z}$

---

So we got the following solutions:

$$x=\frac{\pi n}{2}$$
$$x=\pi n\pm\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the prosthaphaeresis formula,
$$ \sin{A}-\sin{B} = 2\cos{\frac{A+B}{2}}\sin{\frac{A-B}{2}}, $$
we find
$$ 2\cos{3x}\sin{x}=0. $$
Now you just have to solve $\sin{x}=0$ or $\cos{3x}=0$. Sine has zeros at $180n$ degrees for $n$ an integer, and $\cos{y}$ has zeros at $y=180n+90$ degrees. Dividing by $3$ and checking all cases gives the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

First you should use the natural angle unit, which is the *radian*. Second, you should write the general solution, which is always a congruence.

Your equation factors as 
\begin{align*}
2\sin x\cos x(2\cos 2x -1)=0 &\iff\begin{cases}\sin x=0\\ \cos x=0 \\\cos x=\frac12
\end{cases}\\
& \iff 
\begin{cases}
x\equiv 0\mod \pi \\
x\equiv \frac\pi2\mod\pi\\2x\equiv\pm\frac\pi3\mod 2\pi\iff x\pm\frac\pi6\mod \pi
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

[image]